# Packaged Python files into an exe, but it only works on the machine it was packaged on

Tags: python, windows, opencv, package, pyinstaller

So I packaged a few Python files into an .exe for windows. The machine I did it on was a school computer using windows 8. Everything worked well. I uploaded it to my cloud storage and downloaded it on my personal PC (Windows 10).

The program runs, but one of the features (loading a video) does not work. I get an error in the python.

Any ideas?

The problem is that the video isn't opening. 
**Here is some more info**:

My Python code initially had the same exact errors when running from source. The problem was that I had imported an incompatible opencv. I switched from 3.0.0 to 3.2.0 which fix the source problem. From there I decided to continue with packaging the files into an .exe (using PyInstaller). On the Windows 8 Machine, it worked flawlessly. I decided to share that same exe file on my windows 10 machine and it didn't work. I got errors like I initially did with the wrong opencv. So I decided to package files on my windows 10 machine. I made sure I had the correct packages (PyQt4, opencv etc.) but the same errors were reproduced.

I then tested the .exe file around other Win 8 / Win 7 machines in my lab (School). None worked. **It only works on one computer which I initially built and packaged it on.**

**I am not sure why this is happening. All machines were 64 bit. Or could it be something with my environment variables?**

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much!

**More(Unnecessary) Info:**

This software isn't mine, but rather my mentor's. I am simply helping her debug the issues. **It will then be uploaded online so other people can use it. This is why I want to make sure it works on every machine**
- CS Student, Rising Junior Undergrad

I apologize for such a long post and Thanks again!

Comment: Do all the machines have the *exact* same camera and drivers? And I mean *exact* - same version numbers.

Comment: I am not sure, could you guide me on how to check this? I thought since I used the same version of Opencv, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Different cameras/drivers have different capabilities. Suggest you compare a couple of convenient systems where your exe fails, look at the camera and the drivers, see what makes/version and how they compare to your reference system where it works. Suppose this might not be the cause of your problem, just a guess, but doing this comparison might eliminate this as a possibility if the versions are identical to your reference system.

Comment: I'm not sure where to check for these drivers. Is it in the the device manager? and is it called just "Camera"?

Comment: Side Note - Everything works when compiling and running from source, regardless of the machine (provided that the correct packages were downloaded/imported) using Anaconda 2